# iphone navigation & saving data to plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm creating a small iPhone app, when application lauches, it will ask the user to sign up or Login. If they choose sign up safari will open. This part is done.

```
////button code

button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain]; 
   button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 150, 300, 50);
   [button setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myaction:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
          button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
   [mainView addSubview:button];
   [button release];
```

If they click Login -

1. How to navigate to next window asking for username / password ? Can I do it button action ?

2.How I will store their info in plist ( if i'm correct ) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do (1.) is:

- define a LoginViewController class that inherits from UIViewController
- create a nib file named "login" with the UI elements for your login view
- make your login button action do somehting like:

  LoginViewController *controller = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"login" bundle:nil];
  [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];

Answer (score 0):

There are really several different questions here disguised as one.

1: in the method -buttonAction is where your navigation logic will be.  It looks like you're probably working from xibs out of Interface Builder

2: You'll need to use the NSDictionary method called -writeToFile:atomically:.  The arguments are the path string for the file to be stored on flash memory, and a BOOL YES/NO value that determines if the file is written immediately, or if it checks for errors first.  I'd recommend setting atomically: to YES.

I'm gathering from your question that you're not familiar with Cocoa and UIKit.  You'll be hard pressed to get a tutorial on how to put your application together.  You're going to need to try Google for swapping views and handling page navigation.  It's a lot deeper than what I'm describing here.

Comment: 1. Yes, I'm not using interface builder.
2. I hope you understand my requirement, could you tell me where should I start reading and please point a good tutorial which helps me to solve this ?